# black dots on 9patch image

Tags: android, nine-patch

My app is showing the 9patch black marks. Why could it be?

That's my picture:

[image]

You can see the small black dots. The file name is "filename.9.png".
I am using the 9patch program that comes with android sdk.
That's my code:

```
<ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/left_scroll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/pic_coupon_calender"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/pic_coupon_news" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
```

The background is "pic_coupons_news.9.png".
What could be the reasons for such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you switched some of them of place? Or maybe you've put accidentaly a line on a second pixel row or something like that?

Comment: Use draw9patch.bat (on Windows) to investigate your `pic_coupons_news.9.png` drawable.

Comment: TimVK: its one big picture with 5 squers in it. i counld not replace any thing in there....  its not a number of images.  
StenaviN: im on a mac...  thank you both.

Comment: Post your image here. The 9-patch

Comment: I said about your 9-patch.`pic_coupons_news.9.png` Not the screenshot or whatever it is.

Comment: its not a screen shot. i added the image. i dont know how to put the file itself on this page..  sorry.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying with "its one big picture with 5 squares in it" and I think that's your problem. You need to create all the images on their own and then add them to your application. I hope this is a little bit of help.

Comment: no...  its just a demo. i dont neet it to really be more than one big image. i did the 9patch on the big image. i dont see what is the size of the image got to do with it?  only small pictures can 9patch?!

Comment: black dots / lines on the border of 9patch images specify the regions that can be stretched (top&left) and hold the content (bottom&right). See http://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Kj3.png

Comment: zapl: so?  i know that. why do i see the dots in my app?

Comment: I don't know. Either your black pixels are not border pixels but somewhere inside - or your image is for some other reason not considered 9patch

Comment: :)  Thanks, but thy r border pixel.

Comment: after some testing, i found out that u cant 9patch ont image that is bigger then the screen...  is that possible?

Comment: Normally the reason that you see the border is that your 9patch couldn't be processed by Android, and defaults to a regular png.  Are there gaps in your black dots on the right or bottom of the image?  It might help to see the actual 9patch, you can upload it the same way you uploaded the screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened with me once too.

Just **clean your project and rebuild**. This should resolve the defect.

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound unfamiliar. Additionally, you check by uninstalling the app and installing it back (along with clean and rebuild).